# How to get CreateTransaction address from PowerShell

Tags: c++, powershell, pinvoke

I want to get the addess of the function `CreateTransaction` in PowerShell.

I know how to do it in C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *CreateTransaction)
(
    IN LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpTransactionAttributes OPTIONAL,
    IN LPGUID                UOW OPTIONAL,
    IN DWORD                 CreateOptions OPTIONAL,
    IN DWORD                 IsolationLevel OPTIONAL,
    IN DWORD                 IsolationFlags OPTIONAL,
    IN DWORD                 Timeout OPTIONAL,
    IN LPWSTR                Description OPTIONAL
    );

int main()
{
    HMODULE hKtmw32 = GetModuleHandle(L"Ktmw32.dll");
    CreateTransaction createTransaction = (CreateTransaction)GetProcAddress(hKtmw32, "CreateTransaction");

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do it in PowerShell ?
I tried to use the below function to do it.
It works fine with other functions but not with `CreateTransaction`.

```
function Local:Get-ProcAddress
{
    Param
    (
        [OutputType([IntPtr])]

        [Parameter( Position = 0, Mandatory = $True )]
        [String]
        $Module,

        [Parameter( Position = 1, Mandatory = $True )]
        [String]
        $Procedure
    )

    # Get a reference to System.dll in the GAC
    $SystemAssembly = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
        Where-Object { $_.GlobalAssemblyCache -And $_.Location.Split('\\')[-1].Equals('System.dll') }
    $UnsafeNativeMethods = $SystemAssembly.GetType('Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods')
    # Get a reference to the GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress methods
    $GetModuleHandle = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetModuleHandle')
    $GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress')
    # Get a handle to the module specified
    $Kern32Handle = $GetModuleHandle.Invoke($null, @($Module))
    $hexAddrs = [convert]::ToString($Kern32Handle.ToInt32(), 16)
    Write-Host "[*] Got $($Module) at 0x$($hexAddrs)"
    $tmpPtr = New-Object IntPtr
    $HandleRef = New-Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef($tmpPtr, $Kern32Handle)

    # Return the address of the function
    Write-Output $GetProcAddress.Invoke($null, @([System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef]$HandleRef, $Procedure))
}

Get-ProcAddress Ktmw32.dll CreateTransaction # => DOES NOT WORK
Get-ProcAddress ntdll.dll NtCreateSection    # => WORKS
```

Reference:
https://github.com/HarmJ0y/Misc-PowerShell/blob/master/Get-System.ps1

I don't know why it doesn't return me the address of `CreateTransaction`.

I have workaround to call the function but it still interesting me how can I get the function address with PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace PInvoke {

    public class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES { 
            int nLength;  
            IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor; 
            int bInheritHandle;
        }
        [DllImport("Ktmw32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] 
        public static extern IntPtr CreateTransaction( 
                 SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes, 
                 IntPtr guid, int options, int isolationLevel, int isolationFlags, 
                 int milliSeconds, string description
        ); 
    }
}
"@  

$Class1 = New-Object PInvoke.Program
$struct = New-Object PInvoke.Program+SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
[PInvoke.Program]::CreateTransaction($struct, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "notepad.exe")
```

Comment: Does `Write-Host "[*] Got $($Module) at 0x$($hexAddrs)"` return anything?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Just output to the string. You can ignore this row or remove it.

Comment: I know what `Write-Host` does. The question was, does it show you anything meaningfull? Did the GetModuleHandle at least succeed?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers No, the `GetModuleHandle` for `Ktmw32.dll` failed.

Comment: @E235 Ehh, why would `powershell.exe` map the KTM library? `Get-Process ntdll.dll NtCreateSection` works because `ntdll.dll` is already loaded into memory, `KtmW32.dll` isn't

Comment: You've beat me to it <g>. @E235 - Using your C++ example, somewhere you have got to load KtmW32.dll don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why it doesn't return me the address of CreateTransaction.

In all likelihood, it doesn't return the address because **it doesn't exist** - I can't think of a single module or facility in PowerShell that depend on `KtmW32.dll`, so assuming that it would have been loaded by `powershell.exe` seems naive.

You can inspect this by interrogating the `Modules` property of the current process:

```
(Get-Process -Id $PID).Modules
```

---

As an alternative to `Add-Type`, you can load the library into the process manually via [`SafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/SafeNativeMethods.cs,164):

```
$SystemAssembly = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
    Where-Object { $_.GlobalAssemblyCache -And $_.Location.Split('\\')[-1].Equals('System.dll') } |Select -First 1
$SafeNativeMethods = $SystemAssembly.GetType('Microsoft.Win32.SafeNativeMethods')
$KtmW32 = $SafeNativeMethods::LoadLibrary('KtmW32.dll')
```

Now you can use `Get-ProcAddress` as in your example, or use the module handle returned by `LoadLibrary` directly:

```
# Same as before
$UnsafeNativeMethods = $SystemAssembly.GetType('Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods')
$GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress')

$tmpPtr = New-Object IntPtr

# Now use the module handle from LoadLibrary instead
$HandleRef = New-Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef($tmpPtr, $KtmW32)

$GetProcAddress.Invoke($null,@([System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef]$handleref,'CreateTransaction'))
```